# hostap error: Configuration file: hostapd.conf nl80211: Could not configure driver mode

Tags: wifi, kali-linux

I spent three days looking for an answer and trust me i did not find a solution.

```
   └─# hostapd hostapd.conf                                                            
Configuration file: hostapd.conf
nl80211: Could not configure driver mode
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan0 disabled_11b_rates=0
nl80211 driver initialization failed.
wlan0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->DISABLED
wlan0: AP-DISABLED 
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING 
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan0 wasn't started
```

I reinstalled `hostapd` and I did kill any task that my interfere with the AP. I have also attempted to restart and kill the `hostapd` before running it again and still no fix.

My chipset is MT7601u and it does support AP mode and i did try it using

```
airbase-ng -e 'APtest" -c 8 wlan0
```

and it actually worked and showed me who connected to the network, the chipset is supported by kali linux as they added it to their kernel.

Comment: Could it be that these module parameters are incorrect: `deinit ifname=wlan0 disabled_11b_rates=0`?

Comment: @berndbausch I don't think so i checked the name its correct and this is truly confusing i can't find the problem its like 1 hidden problem causing 8 problems after it.

Comment: Just had this exact same error message and just had to run it with `sudo`

Comment: @darthmaule2 That's so useless, do you think i didn't try that?

Comment: I have been having the same error. However if you use airbase-ng to create ap it will work (but slow). It has something to do with hostapd so if you find any workaround let me know.